# WPF Binding Return StaticResource as String

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I created a custom checkbox using a UserControl with Image and Label inside. I want to swap the Checked and Unchecked images whenever i click it.
So far i tried doing the following

```
<Image Source="{Binding StateImage}"/>
```

I have a property named StateImage

```
public String StateImage
{
     get
     {
         return is_checked?"{StaticResource Checked}":"StaticResource Unchecked";
     }
}
```

My code doesn't work and i ended up doing like this:

```
public String StateImage
    {
         get
         {
             return is_checked?"/Resources/Images/Checked.png":"/Resources/Images/Unchecked.png";
         }
    }
```

the `is_checked` variable is modified under MouseDown Event of the UserControl

Is there an easier way I can call the image without writing the whole path and filename?

Comment: You can always ditch the `UserControl` and create a custom control based on `Checkbox`, have different image properties for each state and swap the images via `ControlTemplate.Triggers`. However, this suggestion is a bit far from your question, so I don't feel like it should be a full blown answer for now.

Comment: You wouldn't even need a custom control. An appropriate CheckBox Style is sufficient.

Comment: I'm new to WPF and I'm having a hard time analyzing control templates. That's why I used a method I am comfortable with. But I guess, there's no  other way but to study on how to override their default template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the resources as `strings` in the `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <s:String x:Key="Checked">pic.png</s:String>
        <s:String x:Key="UnChecked"></s:String>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Background="Yellow">
        <Image Source="{Binding StateImage}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

```
private bool is_checked;
public String StateImage
{
    get
    {
        return is_checked ? Resources["Checked"] as string : Resources["UnChecked"] as string;
    }
}
```